# iPhone adding black space on the top of status bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, statusbar

Not sure how to explain this, Have added some images below. Not sure what I have changed but it seems my app has now got black bar above and below the app. Before the status bar was sitting on the top of the device. I have tried playing around with the auto layout but didnt seems to help at all. can some one please help.

[image: old screen]

[image: new screen]

Comment: Looks like you're running the app on a 4" device but did not include a 4" launch screen

Comment: you need to support iPhone 5 screen size (4"), and those gaps will disappear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to support the iPhone 5 screen size (4 inches).

Add a launch image with the appropriate size (look in your image assets folder) and your app will then adapt to this device's screen.

Note that you should also support the new iPhone 6 and 6 Plus screens sizes and add the appropriate launch images.

Comment: awesome. thanks for that. I think its the new images my designer has sent. I didnt check the size.